# Is there any way to make a fake call from Ktor to itself, to make request pass through all pipeline?

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, httpserver, ktor

I have an ktor web server that successfully responds on http requests. Now there is a need to read data from kafka's topic and process it.
Is there any way send the data I've read to ktor, like this data came from outside, to make it pass through all pipeline, like ContentNegotiation and other features?

Application class has method execute(), which takes ApplicationCall, but I've found zero examples - how can I fill my implementation of this class properly. Especially route - do I need the real one? Would be nice if this route would be private and would be unavailable from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [withTestApplication](https://ktor.io/docs/testing.html) function to test your application's modules without making an actual network connection. Here is an example:

```
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.request.*
import io.ktor.response.*
import io.ktor.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.testing.*
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class SimpleTest {
    @Test
    fun test() = withTestApplication {
        application.module()
        // more modules to test here

        handleRequest(HttpMethod.Post, "/post") {
            setBody("kafka data")
        }.response.let { response ->
            assertEquals("I get kafka data", response.content)
        }
    }
}

fun Application.module() {
    routing {
        post("/post") {
            call.respondText { "I get ${call.receiveText()}" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May be my explanation wasn't exact. I don't need it for testing. My application is running and reading kafka's topic all the time. When some data is read from topic (i.e. string with json shaped value:
 {"id" : 123,"registrationDate": "2020-10-10", "userName":"Bill"}
I want to send this data to my application like it came from other microservice - to some system route that is not available from outside.
Gson will deserialize it as some model i.e. User, and my service will put it to DB.

Comment: So the part between I get data from kafka and recieved it at my DB service is a question :)
The purpose is to use default ktor pipeline with content negotiation and other features like in http-requests but for internal calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @AlekseiTirman answer is great and most probably you should go for it

But I have to mention that it's easy to do it even in "real life" run. Your local machine ip is `0.0.0.0`, you can get port from the env variable, so you just can create a simple `HttpClient` and send a request:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    delay(1000)
    val client = HttpClient {
        defaultRequest {
            // actually this is already a default value so no need to setting it
            host = "0.0.0.0"
            port = environment.config.property("ktor.deployment.port").getString().toInt()
        }
    }
    val result = client.get<String>("good")
    println("local response $result")
}

routing {
    get("good") {
        call.respond("hello world")
    }
}
```